# Changing forms between standard calculator and scientific with menu items in Java

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I have a standard calculator and a scientific calculator created in java, both with menu bars and the menu items "standard" and "scientific" to switch between the two, but I can't figure out how to actually have the calculator change when the options are clicked.

Code so far:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class regCalc implements ActionListener 
{    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Standard Calculator");

    //JPanels for standard and scientific
    JPanel panelstand = new JPanel (new FlowLayout ()); 
    JPanel panelsci = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu view = new JMenu ("View");
    JMenuItem standard = new JMenuItem("Standard");
    JMenuItem scientific = new JMenuItem("Scientific");

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea (1,20);

    JButton but1 = new JButton ("1");
    JButton but2 = new JButton ("2");
    JButton but3 = new JButton ("3");
    JButton but4 = new JButton ("4");
    JButton but5 = new JButton ("5");
    JButton but6 = new JButton ("6");
    JButton but7 = new JButton ("7");
    JButton but8 = new JButton ("8");
    JButton but9 = new JButton ("9");
    JButton but0 = new JButton ("0");

    JButton butAdd = new JButton ("+");
    JButton butSub = new JButton ("-");
    JButton butMult = new JButton ("*");
    JButton butDiv = new JButton ("/");
    JButton butEq = new JButton ("=");
    JButton butClear = new JButton ("C");

    Double number1, number2, result;
    int addc =0, subc=0, multc=0, divc=0;

    public void ui()
    {
    frame.setVisible(true);

    panelstand.setVisible(true);
    panelsci.setVisible(false);

    frame.setSize(270,230);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    view.add(standard);
    view.add(scientific);
    menuBar.add(view);

    frame.add(panelstand);

    panelstand.add(text);

    panelstand.add(but1);
    panelstand.add(but2);
    panelstand.add(but3);
    panelstand.add(but4);
    panelstand.add(but5);
    panelstand.add(but6);
    panelstand.add(but7);
    panelstand.add(but8);
    panelstand.add(but9);
    panelstand.add(but0);

    panelstand.add(butAdd);
    panelstand.add(butSub);
    panelstand.add(butMult);
    panelstand.add(butDiv);
    panelstand.add(butEq);
    panelstand.add(butClear);

    but1.addActionListener(this);
    but2.addActionListener(this);
    but3.addActionListener(this);
    but4.addActionListener(this);
    but5.addActionListener(this);
    but6.addActionListener(this);
    but7.addActionListener(this);
    but8.addActionListener(this);
    but9.addActionListener(this);
    but0.addActionListener(this);

    butAdd.addActionListener(this);
    butSub.addActionListener(this);
    butMult.addActionListener(this);
    butDiv.addActionListener(this);
    butEq.addActionListener(this);
    butClear.addActionListener(this);   
}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source == but1)
    {
        text.append("1");
    }

    if (source == but2)
    {
        text.append("2");
    }

    if (source == but3)
    {
        text.append("3");
    }

    if (source == but4)
    {
        text.append("4");
    }

    if (source == but5)
    {
        text.append("5");
    }

    if (source == but6)
    {
        text.append("6");
    }

    if (source == but7)
    {
        text.append("7");
    }

    if (source == but8)
    {
        text.append("8");
    }

    if (source == but9)
    {
        text.append("9");
    }

    if (source == but0)
    {
        text.append("0");
    }

    if (source == butAdd)
    {
        number1=number_Reader();
        text.setText("");
        addc=1;
        subc=0;
        multc=0;
        divc=0;
    }

    if (source == butSub)
    {
        number1=number_Reader();
        text.setText("");
        addc=0;
        subc=1;
        multc=0;
        divc=0;
    }

    if (source == butMult)
    {
        number1=number_Reader();
        text.setText("");
        addc=0;
        subc=0;
        multc=1;
        divc=0;
    }

    if (source == butDiv)
    {
        number1=number_Reader();
        text.setText("");
        addc=0;
        subc=0;
        multc=0;
        divc=1;
    }

    if (source == butEq)
    {
        number2=number_Reader();
        if (addc > 0)
        {
            result = number1+number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }

        if (subc > 0)
        {
            result = number1-number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }

        if (multc > 0)
        {
            result = number1*number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }

        if (divc > 0)
        {
            result = number1/number2;
            text.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }
    }

    if (source == butClear)
    {
        number1=0.0;
        number2=0.0;
        text.setText("");
    }

    if (view == scientific)
    {
        frame.add(scientific);
    }

}

    public double number_Reader()
    {
        double num1;
        String s;
        s=text.getText();
        num1=Double.valueOf(s);
        return num1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be after something such as [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which enables you to use a layout to switch between two panels.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, while I'm a big promoter of CardLayout, I would ask you to consider an alternative. If you think about the problem, you'll see (at least in my mind) that you don't want to completely *change* views when switching calculator types, but rather you want to augment or diminish views, since the standard calculator is really just a sub-set of the scientific calculator. So what you could do is simply display an additional JPanel with the scientific buttons present if scientific calculator is needed, and hide the JPanel when the standard calculator is required. This can be done by adding the JPanels to an appropriate layout, say BorderLayout with the standard JPanel added BorderLayout.CENTER and the scientific JPanel BorderLayout.PAGE_END, and then call `setVisible(true)` or false on the scientific JPanel. Make sure to call `repaint()` on the JPanel that holds the Scientific calculator.

Comment: Good suggestion. I just tried it on the standard OS X calculator and it does exactly that (until you switch to programmers mode ...). The only thing I would change is to add the display (where the result appears) in the NORTH, so that the display spans both panels when switching to scientific mode

Comment: Yep, correct. Though @berry's answer is a very good one and a valid solution for this as well. 1+ to him.

Comment: thanks a ton! ill let you all know if i have any further questions.

Comment: Do you know I would go about combining the codes? I have them each created as two separate classes

Comment: @dannyh: Hard to say anything without seeing your code or knowing more about how your program is set up. Hopefully you don't have classes that extend JFrame -- and this is one example why that's not a good thing to do.

Comment: they are both just tutorial type codes that I pulled from the internet. the menu items and switching between the two calcs is what my project is all about

Comment: will it allow me to post the codes in this comment box? or is there a special place i need to that?

Comment: @dannyh: You would need to edit your question to show code. And regarding "borrowed" code, better that you use the ideas from the code, but write your own code, code that's geared towards making JPanels, not JFrames.

Comment: Okay I'll post something as soon as I get some changes made to it. Thanks again. I appreciate it very much

Comment: okay there is what i have. i created a jpanel for each and set the scientific one to false while the standard is true

Comment: +1, neat solution I didn't consider for the calculator use case!